# is ENOENT from fs.createReadStream uncatchable?

Tags: node.js

I'm not able to catch ENOENT of fs.createReadStream(). Is this an asynchronous function , which throws exception  in a different closure-chain ?

```
$ node -v
v0.10.9
$ cat a.js
fs = require('fs')

try  {
  x = fs.createReadStream('foo');
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Caught" );
}

$ node a.js

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open 'foo'
```

I am expecting 'Caught' to be printed rather than error stack !

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`fs.createReadStream` is asynchronous with the event emitter style and does not throw exceptions (which only make sense for synchronous code). Instead it will emit an error event.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const stream = fs.createReadStream('foo');
stream.on('error', function (error) {console.log("Caught", error);});
stream.on('ready', function () {stream.read();});
```

Comment: I guess you're saying the stream object is returned synchronously, but the opening of its file happens asynchronously with event emission. Is there no chance the error event will be emitted before `stream.on('error', ...)` takes effect? That's what I see if I type this into node's REPL a line at a time.

Comment: Yes, you can be assured that the current tick will complete before any events fire. So as long as you bind your handlers right away, all is well.

Comment: Hmm that's really confusing behaviour!

Comment: Thanks for this. Very helpful. Why don't I see this in the docs anywhere? (I'm assuming I'm misreading the docs in some fundamental fashion)

Comment: The docs describe the `error` event from ReadableStream [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#stream_event_error_1). You might have a hard time finding it because you have to start at the `createReadStream` docs and click the link to navigate to `ReadableStream` to find details on the events emitted.