# fs.createReadStream error; uncaughtException: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, stream

I was doing some file processing in the stream pipe and wanted to test some error conditions. The first thing that came to my mind was open not existing file. And I found out that I cannot handle this situation. It looks like node.fs doesn't emit an 'error' event. Does anybody know how to handle the case? I have read that there is the same situation with fs.unlink.

```
const fName = 'C:/temp/fff.txt';
const outStream = fs.createWriteStream(fName + '.enc');
console.log(`-- 1111 ${fName} `);
fs.createReadStream(fName)
.pipe(outStream)
.on('open', () => {
  console.log(`ON OPEN  ${fName}`);
})
.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`ON ERROR ${fName}; an error happened: ${err.message}`);
})
.on('close', () => {
  console.log(`ON CLOSE  ${fName}`);
})
.on('end', () => {
  console.log(`ON END  ${fName}`);
});
console.log(`-- 2222 ${fName} `);
```

If file exists the output:

```
-- 1111 C:/temp/fff.txt
-- 2222 C:/temp/fff.txt
...
ON OPEN  C:/temp/fff.txt
ON CLOSE  C:/temp/fff.txt
```

If file doesn't exist:

```
-- 1111 C:/temp/fff.txt
-- 2222 C:/temp/fff.txt
...
ON OPEN  C:/temp/fff.txt
2022-06-13T19:28:48.379Z; error; uncaughtException: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\temp\ffff.txt'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\temp\ffff.txt';

C:\Users\p>
```

Similar issue: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136536/is-enoent-from-fs-createreadstream-uncatchable)

People ask: *Is there a chance the error event will be emitted before stream.on('error', ...) takes effect?*

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use fs.stat first to check if the file exists

Answer (score 2):

Looks like stream.pipe does not forward the 'error' events, so if you want to handle the errors you would need to do something like below, or use [stream.pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback)

```
rstream
   .on('error', handleError)
   .pipe(foo)
   .on('error', handleError)
   .pipe(bar)
   .on('error', handleError);
```

Thanks to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771220/error-handling-with-node-js-streams)